# to compare two fields of the same collection

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I want to compare two fields of the same collection (Mysql query example "SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE t.field1 > t.filed2;") in mongodb with cakephp. I cannot use '$where' and aggregate of mongodb as I am also using other operators of mongodb like $or, $and and etc. And also I am using find of mongodb.

Ex: Collection have two fields integer fields per_day_budget and today_spent and I want to get the list of records where today_spent is less than or equal to per_day_budget. I hope this will you to better understand my query.

Kindly suggest solution for the same.

Comment: If possible give an example of your document in your question??

Comment: Ex: Collection have two fields integer fields per_day_budget and today_spent and I want to get the list of records where today_spent is less than or equal to per_day_budget. I hope this will you to better understand my query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 db.collection.find({ this.today_spent : {$lte : this.per_day_budget}});
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful however below works for us...Thanks for support..
db.collection.find( {"size":"300_250","$and":[{"status":3},{"$or":[{"timelimit":"2"},{"$where":"this.today_spent <= this.per_day_budget","timelimit":"1"}]}]} )